# Yahoo Mail App - Send Email To Contact List

Tags: contacts, contact-groups, yahoo-mail

I have created several contact lists in my Yahoo e-mail account by using Yahoo's website via Internet Explorer.  I would like to send an e-mail to one of the contact lists from my Android phone (which is a Galaxy S4), but I can't figure out how...  Here is what I've tried so far:

1. Unable To Access Contact Lists From Yahoo Mail App:  I tried accessing the contact lists from the Yahoo Mail App, which I installed on the phone, but I can't find the lists anywhere.  My contacts all appear in the app, and the information seems to be read-only.  I can't edit their names or any of their details, and I can only access a list of all of my contacts when I try to compose an e-mail and touch the "To" field in the newly composed e-mail.  There is no mention of the lists to which they belong.
2. Unable To Create New Contact Lists As Groups On Android Device By Syncing With Yahoo Account:  I went into the Yahoo Mail App Settings and selected "Sync Yahoo contacts".  This imported the contacts into my Android contacts, but it did not assign them to any groups.  If they belonged to contact lists in my Yahoo account, no new groups were created.  Also, existing groups on my phone that matched the names of contact lists in my Yahoo account were ignored and not used when the contacts were imported.

I realize that I could manually recreate the groups on my Android device and assign all contacts to them, but this would be a very tedious and time consuming solution to a process that seems to beg for automation.  Is there a quick way of doing this?

If necessary, is there another app I can download that is safe to use which will accomplish the task?  I tried the above solutions using Gmail as a workaround, but encountered the same obstacles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I just figured out a workaround. You can export your Yahoo Contact Lists by:

1. Signing into your Yahoo Account via their web interface,
2. Clicking on the "Contacts" icon, and
3. Choosing "Actions" => "Export".

This will create a CSV file which can then be used to import the contacts into a Gmail account via Google's web interface. After that, you can sync your Gmail contacts to your phone using the Android Gmail app. This will create the contact lists from Yahoo and import them into your phone as contact groups on the device.

Comment: Laurence Marks commented: "*Not bad, but it's a one-time fix. If I add someone to a list on my desktop it won't transfer to the phone or tablet. I'd have to jump through hoops again. Yahoo really needs to provide this function.*"